# Integer time shifts under Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-transform

Denote the Fourier transform of a given function $f$ by
$$\widehat{f}(w)=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} f(t)e^{-2\pi i wt}dt.$$
Let $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and define $f_c$ as the time-shifted $f$,
$$f_c(t)=f(t+c).$$
So its Fourier transform is
$$\widehat{f_c}(w)=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} f(t+c)e^{-2\pi i wt}dt$$
$$=e^{-2\pi i w c}\widehat{f}(w).$$
Then, if $c$ is integer,
$$\widehat{f_c}(w) = e^{(-2\pi i c )w }\widehat{f}(w) = (e^{-2\pi i c })^w =1^w\widehat{f}(w) = \widehat{f}(w),$$
contradicting the Fourier inversion theorem!
What is wrong with my argument?

Comment: $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} f(t+c)e^{-2\pi i wt}dt= \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} f(u)e^{-2\pi i w(u-c)}du = e^{2\pi i w c}\widehat{f}(w)$. And it is not true that $e^{ab} = (e^a)^b$ for $a,b$ non positive. What is true is $e^r = e^s$ iff $r - s = 2i \pi k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [reuns](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/276986/reuns) describes in the question comment, and it's also stated in the answer by [user21820](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/21820/user21820) in [Why $e^{i(π/3)} \ne -1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714618/why-ei%cf%80-3-ne-1), the basic issue is that

> It is **not at all true** that $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$ for complex numbers $x,a,b$ in general, under any reasonable definition of complex exponentiation.

The answer provides a quite good explanation of why this is the case, including providing several counter-examples, and the specific general cases where you can state that $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$ does hold. In your case, you are assuming this in

> $e^{(-2\pi i c )w }\widehat{f}(w) = (e^{-2\pi i c })^w$