# What happens if an integer is raised to an imaginary power?

Tags: complex-numbers

When I raise some integer to some imaginary power I obtain a complex number. E.g., $$2^i = 0.7692 + 0.6390i.$$

Why does this happen? What does it mean to raise an integer to an imaginary power?

Comment: Note $$2^i=e^{i\ln(2)}=\cos(\ln(2))+i\sin(\ln(2))$$

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: I guess I need an intuitive answer

Answer (score 0):

Let $n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}\,$ and $\,p\in\mathbb R.$

By definition, $$n^{p\,i} = \exp\left[p\,i\,\log\left(n\right)\right]
\\ = \begin{cases}\exp\left[p\,i\,\left(\ln(n)+i\,2k\pi\right)\right] &\text{if }n>0;
\\ \exp\left[p\,i\,\left(\ln(-n)+i(2k+1)\pi\right)\right] &\text{if }n<0 \end{cases}
\\ = \begin{cases}\exp\left[-2pk\pi\right] \,\exp\left[i\,p\ln(n)\right] &\text{if }n>0;
\\ \exp\left[-p(2k+1)\pi\right] \,\exp\left[i\,p\ln(-n)\right] &\text{if }n<0 \end{cases},$$ where $k\in\mathbb Z.$

Comment: @Ulziibayar On a related note: [What happens when an integer is raised to an irrational power?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3804755/21813)

Comment: P.S. For readability, $\exp()$ denotes $e^{()},$ and is not necessarily single-valued.